# Google Cloud Platform + Confluence Server + SMTP

Tags: smtp, google-cloud-platform, confluence

I am trying to migrate my Confluence server to live in a vm hosted in Google Cloud Platform.

So far so good, I got mostly everything working, except my mail setup.

[image]

I read in google's documentation that those ports are blocked due to security issues and past bad experiences, see here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/.

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. By default, these outbound SMTP ports are blocked because of the large amount of abuse these ports are susceptible to

Has anybody had any luck with similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after checking with some collegues, they had the same issue, and apparently in my case, since I am using AWS I can use another port they have available in their smtp setup, port *2587*, this port has not been blocked by google so I was able to use that one instead of *587*

I hope this helps someone else

more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html